# Call to undefined function odbc_connect() on Windows Server 2008

Tags: php, odbc

I installed XAMPP on Windows Server 2008. Apache is running with PHP 7.0.13. I modified php.ini file for to enable ODBC driver, like this:

`extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll`

Even, I see ODBC in PDO drivers section when I use `phpinfo()`. But, I get an error when I use `odbc_connect`.

How fix this? Please, help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP offers two kinds of support for ODBC (and most database drivers):

- [Through PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php)
- [Standalone](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php)

You have enabled the *PDO* version (`php_pdo_odbc.dll`), but you're trying to use a [non-PDO function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php). You've got two options:

- Enable the standalone functionality via `php_odbc.dll` (note the slightly different name)
- Use ODBC via the PDO interface

[PDO is](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

> a lightweight, consistent interface for accessing databases in PHP

and I generally prefer it to the database-specific interfaces, but either should work.

Comment: GREAT! GREAT!! Thanks! I had to enable php_odbc.dll.

I didn't know that exists diferents ways. Thanks.